# tcl find the max element of a list

Tags: tcl

i am new to tcl , i am trying to get the max element in a given list 
i  wrote a function that prints the max but it is not working properly
here is the code

```
proc findmax { items } {
  set max 1
  foreach i $items { 
    if { $i > $max } {
      set $max $i
    }
  }
  puts "max is = $max"
}
```

and i called the function like this :

```
findmax $items
```

this is the list i passed :

```
set items { 12 2 5 4 2 6 7 55 8 9 6 4}
```

but it outputs 1 and not 55 as expected

Comment: `set $max $i` -- What is the first argument to the `set` command, a variable *name* or a variable *value*?

Comment: Also, a safer way to set the initial value for max is to use the first element of the list: consider the case where all the list elements are negative: `set max [lindex $items 0]`

Comment: about setting the max as the first element in the list i totally agree. thank you so much ! i found where i was wrong

Comment: set max $i instead of set $max $i !!! you pointed me to the problem

Comment: Finding the maximum value of a list is a one-liner in Tcl anyway: `set max [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$items]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
set $max $i
```

In Tcl, the `$` character means *read* from the named variable and use that value as (possibly part of) the argument to a command. It means this *always*. No exceptions (unless backslash-quoted or in `{`braces`}`, of course). Thus, on the first iteration of the loop you're getting (after substitution):

```
set 1 12
```

The variable name `1` is legal, but unusual and not what you want. For the algorithm to work, you instead want to give the `set` command the *name* of the variable to set, `max`, resulting in this:

```
set max $i
```

which will be substituted to this on the first iteration:

```
set max 12
```

That looks right! A good rule of thumb for future programming is that if a command manipulates a variable (setting it or updating it) then you need to pass the name of the variable, not the value retrieved from it.

---

The standard method of getting the maximum value of a list is a one-liner:

```
set max [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$items]
```

This uses the built-in function `max` (which is in the `::tcl::mathfunc` namespace) and passes the contents of the list in `items` as multiple arguments, all as one step. The `{*}$` sequence is a combination of the variable-read syntax rule with the list-expansion rule, which you've probably not really thought about yet. However it's still a good exercise to write your own maximum finder as a learning exercise.