# function to calculate the sum of a given array

Tags: tcl

I am new to Tcl so i am learning the basics. I wrote a function to calculate the sum of an array and print its elements. Here is the code

```
proc print_sum { tab } {
    set s 0
    foreach key [array names tab] {
        puts "${key}=$tab($key)"
        incr $s $tab($key)  
    }
    puts "the sum = $s"
}
```

Here is how I called it:

```
print_sum tab
```

and I created the tab like this:

```
set tab("1") 41
set tab("m2") 5
set tab("3") 3
set tab("tp") 9
set tab("2") 7
set tab("100") 16
```

But the output is wrong! It outputs 0 instead of the actual sum and it does not output any element. But when I used the code directly without writing it in a function, it works.

Comment: Welcome! Pls. provide an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried. The snippets you show do not execute as is without error. For example, `print_sum $tab` for sure will not succeed but will give sth. along the lines of `can't read "tab": variable is array`. Seems to me as you rewrote your example before posting, not actually executing what you posted.

Comment: Other than that: Watch out for [`incr`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm) expecting a variable name (`s`), not its currently hold value (`$s`). Also, you might want to consider using [`tcl::mathop::+`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm#M7) rather than stepwise `incr`.

Comment: I updated my code.. Now it executes fine but the output is still 0

Comment: No, your edit just works around one error condition. It does not resolve it. First, make sure that you understand [how to pass around an array in Tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513266/passing-arrays-to-functions-in-tcl-only-upvar). Second, look at my previous comment regarding `incr`. One step at a time, you baked two problems into your snippet.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I got it now

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364162/tcl-find-the-max-element-of-a-list (it's the _identical_ problem, despite being over a list instead of an array).

Comment: @DonalFellows good catch. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing the string "tab" to the proc, and then you store that in the variable name "tab". This is just a plain variable, not an array, so when you do `array names tab`, you get an empty list back. The foreach loop loops zero times, and the sum is still zero.

You need to use the [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) command to link to the "tab" array in the caller's stack frame:

```
proc print_sum { arrayName } {
    upvar 1 $arrayName a         ;# "alias" the array in the caller's scope
    set s 0
    foreach key [array names a] {
        puts "${key}=$a($key)"
        incr s $a($key)          ;# increment the *variable* not the *variablevalue*
    }
    puts "the sum = $s"
}
print_sum tab
```

outputs

```
"tp"=9
"100"=16
"1"=41
"2"=7
"3"=3
"m2"=5
the sum = 81
```

Comment: works perfectly !! sorry the question may seem stupid to you but to me it is not , thank you

Comment: Not stupid at all. I hope I didn't give you that impression: the upvar command is a bit tricky, but once you understand how it works, you can start writing commands that make your code look a lot more Tcl-ish.